# Problems connecting to WSE3 service with usernameForCertifcate policy using Metro

Tags: web-services, webservice-client, java-metro-framework, wse3.0

I am connecting to a WSE3 service and have been battling for more than a week now using Metro 2.1.1. Part of the problem is that the wsdl did not contain the policy assertions and the guys at the other end used a turnkey usernameForCertifcate policy which I list below. The metro message looks similar to their sample, except for some different ordering and a few other cosmetic things (like metro adds xsi:type="KeyInfoType").

The problem I get when using metro is:

**"Referenced security token could not be retrieved ---> WSE590: Failed to resolve the following Key Info"**

```
<faultstring>
    Referenced security token could not be retrieved ---> WSE590: Failed to resolve the following Key Info
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Reference URI="#_4" />
        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </KeyInfo>
</faultstring>
```

I am able to send a sample message of their's successfully with JMeter. So I did the following as well, as a last resort hack as this project hinges on this. I take their message as a template and replace the encrypted and signed data with what is generated by metro. This manages to get past password authentication, but then fails with this:

**"The signature or decryption was invalid"**

That's the only detail I get and am not sure if more logging could be enabled on their side...

#### Microsoft policy:

```
<policy name="AspectClientPolicy">
  <usernameForCertificateSecurity establishSecurityContext="false" renewExpiredSecurityContext="true" requireSignatureConfirmation="false" messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt" requireDerivedKeys="true" ttlInSeconds="300">
    <serviceToken>
      <x509 storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" findValue="CN=AspectWS2" findType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
    </serviceToken>
    <protection>
      <request signatureOptions="IncludeAddressing, IncludeTimestamp, IncludeSoapBody" encryptBody="true" />
      <response signatureOptions="IncludeAddressing, IncludeTimestamp, IncludeSoapBody" encryptBody="true" />
      <fault signatureOptions="IncludeAddressing, IncludeTimestamp, IncludeSoapBody" encryptBody="false" />
    </protection>
  </usernameForCertificateSecurity>
  <requireActionHeader />
</policy>
```

#### WSDL additions:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="ClientKeystorePolicy" 
  xmlns:sc="http://schemas.sun.com/2006/03/wss/client" 
  xmlns:wspp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/wsit/policy" 
  xmlns:scc="http://schemas.sun.com/ws/2006/05/sc/client" >
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sunsp:DisableInclusivePrefixList xmlns:sunsp="http://schemas.sun.com/2006/03/wss/client"></sunsp:DisableInclusivePrefixList> 
            <sc:TrustStore wspp:visibility="private" storepass="XXX" type="JKS" location="XXX"  peeralias="XXX"/>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>

<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="UserNameForCertificate_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:SymmetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:ProtectionToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Never">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:RequireDerivedKeys />
                                    <sp:RequireThumbprintReference />
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10 />
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:ProtectionToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic256 />
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Strict />
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp />
                    <!-- Have tried with and without this following element /-->
                    <!-- sp:EncryptSignature /-->
                    <sp:SignBeforeEncrypting />
                    <!-- Have tried with and without this following element /-->
                    <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody />
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SymmetricBinding>
            <sp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:WssUsernameToken10 />
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:UsernameToken>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
            <sp:Wss11 xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier />
                    <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial />
                    <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint />
                    <sp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey />
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Wss11>
            <sp:Trust13 xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens />
                    <sp:RequireClientEntropy />
                    <sp:RequireServerEntropy />
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Trust13>
               <sp:EncryptedParts>
                    <sp:Body />
                </sp:EncryptedParts>
                <sp:SignedParts>
                    <sp:Body/>
                    <sp:Header Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"/>
                </sp:SignedParts>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

#### Metro message:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wsc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc"
    xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:exc14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
    <S:Header>
        <To xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" wsu:Id="_5004">XXX</To>
        <Action xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" wsu:Id="_5005">XXX</Action>
        <ReplyTo xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" wsu:Id="_5006">
            <Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</Address>
        </ReplyTo>
        <MessageID xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" wsu:Id="_5007">uuid:145a0194-dd4e-40fe-a7f3-9785885bae37</MessageID>
        <wsse:Security S:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:ns19="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" xmlns:ns18="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" wsu:Id="_5">
                <wsu:Created>2011-09-08T13:08:45Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2011-09-08T13:13:45Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:ns19="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" xmlns:ns18="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" Id="_5002">
                <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" />
                <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="KeyInfoType">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <wsse:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#ThumbprintSHA1" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">XXX
                        </wsse:KeyIdentifier>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
                <xenc:CipherData>
                    <xenc:CipherValue>XXX
                    </xenc:CipherValue>
                </xenc:CipherData>
            </xenc:EncryptedKey>
            <ns19:DerivedKeyToken xmlns:ns19="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" xmlns:ns18="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" wsu:Id="_3">
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                    <wsse:Reference URI="#_5002" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey" />
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                <ns19:Offset>0</ns19:Offset>
                <ns19:Length>24</ns19:Length>
                <ns19:Nonce>XXX</ns19:Nonce>
            </ns19:DerivedKeyToken>
            <ns19:DerivedKeyToken xmlns:ns19="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" xmlns:ns18="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" wsu:Id="_4">
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                    <wsse:Reference URI="#_5002" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey" />
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                <ns19:Offset>0</ns19:Offset>
                <ns19:Length>32</ns19:Length>
                <ns19:Nonce>XXX</ns19:Nonce>
            </ns19:DerivedKeyToken>
            <xenc:ReferenceList xmlns:ns19="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" xmlns:ns18="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
                <xenc:DataReference URI="#_5010" />
                <xenc:DataReference URI="#_5011" />
            </xenc:ReferenceList>
            <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:ns19="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" xmlns:ns18="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" Id="_5011"
                Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
                <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
                <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="KeyInfoType">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#_4" />
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
                <xenc:CipherData>
                    <xenc:CipherValue>XXX
                    </xenc:CipherValue>
                </xenc:CipherData>
            </xenc:EncryptedData>
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ns19="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" xmlns:ns18="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" Id="_1">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1" />
                    <ds:Reference URI="#_5004">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <ds:DigestValue>XXX</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#_5005">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <ds:DigestValue>XXX</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#_5006">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <ds:DigestValue>XXX</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#_5007">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <ds:DigestValue>XXX</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#_5008">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <ds:DigestValue>XXX</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#_5">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <ds:DigestValue>XXX</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#uuid_cb40a9a9-d60d-474a-8d1a-0f59e167de38">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <ds:DigestValue>XXX</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>XXX</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo>
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="_5003">
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#_3" />
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
    </S:Header>
    <S:Body wsu:Id="_5008">
        <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:ns19="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" xmlns:ns18="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" Id="_5010"
            Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content">
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="KeyInfoType">
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                    <wsse:Reference URI="#_4" />
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
            <xenc:CipherData>
                <xenc:CipherValue>XXX
                </xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
        </xenc:EncryptedData>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

#### Their message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action wsu:Id="Id-d330500d-f6c7-44f1-9c41-366a8b113c8b">XXX</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID wsu:Id="Id-5eb5d564-1594-4f15-ab0a-6e8aec86cdc0">urn:uuid:315cae87-7f8b-4ec0-9875-2fcf81594ccb</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:ReplyTo wsu:Id="Id-1fb4bfa4-5c16-494e-8f7d-ad0370e00138">
            <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsa:To wsu:Id="Id-70bd8ebf-580e-424a-86bb-3a64ce02d29a">XXX</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-1a34bff5-908b-4310-8d32-7dad291991ad">
                <wsu:Created>2011-09-06T13:34:56Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2011-09-06T13:39:56Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <xenc:EncryptedKey Id="SecurityToken-047d4682-02bd-424f-9c2d-b4f75b5eb8d7" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
                    <ds:DigestMethod xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                </xenc:EncryptionMethod>
                <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <wsse:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#ThumbprintSHA1" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">XXX</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
                <xenc:CipherData>
                    <xenc:CipherValue>XXX
                </xenc:CipherData>
            </xenc:EncryptedKey>
            <wssc:DerivedKeyToken wsu:Id="SecurityToken-856faf50-7736-41c1-b636-66616a1fb84f" Algorithm="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/dk/p_sha1" xmlns:wssc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                    <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-047d4682-02bd-424f-9c2d-b4f75b5eb8d7" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey" />
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                <wssc:Generation>0</wssc:Generation>
                <wssc:Length>32</wssc:Length>
                <wssc:Label>WS-SecureConversationWS-SecureConversation</wssc:Label>
                <wssc:Nonce>XXX</wssc:Nonce>
            </wssc:DerivedKeyToken>
            <xenc:ReferenceList xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <xenc:DataReference URI="#Enc-519e1e55-9407-4401-a92d-ebcf737b4669" />
                <xenc:DataReference URI="#Enc-6805eb5a-4c80-4bcc-9e21-1fc63051021c" />
            </xenc:ReferenceList>
            <xenc:EncryptedData Id="Enc-519e1e55-9407-4401-a92d-ebcf737b4669" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
                <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-856faf50-7736-41c1-b636-66616a1fb84f" ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/dk" />
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
                <xenc:CipherData>
                    <xenc:CipherValue>XXX</xenc:CipherValue>
                </xenc:CipherData>
            </xenc:EncryptedData>
            <wssc:DerivedKeyToken wsu:Id="SecurityToken-97b849c3-bf59-4b9d-93af-90673b5cc8cb" Algorithm="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/dk/p_sha1" xmlns:wssc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                    <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-047d4682-02bd-424f-9c2d-b4f75b5eb8d7" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey" />
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                <wssc:Generation>0</wssc:Generation>
                <wssc:Length>24</wssc:Length>
                <wssc:Label>WS-SecureConversationWS-SecureConversation</wssc:Label>
                <wssc:Nonce>XXX</wssc:Nonce>
            </wssc:DerivedKeyToken>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" />
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1" />
                    <Reference URI="#SecurityToken-940d8767-aff0-4f07-9a10-ed501106dc74">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>XXX</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#Id-d330500d-f6c7-44f1-9c41-366a8b113c8b">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>XXX</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#Id-5eb5d564-1594-4f15-ab0a-6e8aec86cdc0">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>XXX</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#Id-1fb4bfa4-5c16-494e-8f7d-ad0370e00138">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>XXX</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#Id-70bd8ebf-580e-424a-86bb-3a64ce02d29a">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>XXX</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#Timestamp-1a34bff5-908b-4310-8d32-7dad291991ad">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>XXX</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#Id-93c6fa92-cc95-4d14-abd6-41c27568b004">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>XXX</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>XXX</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-97b849c3-bf59-4b9d-93af-90673b5cc8cb" ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/dk" />
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body wsu:Id="Id-93c6fa92-cc95-4d14-abd6-41c27568b004">
        <xenc:EncryptedData Id="Enc-6805eb5a-4c80-4bcc-9e21-1fc63051021c" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                    <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-856faf50-7736-41c1-b636-66616a1fb84f" ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/dk" />
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
            <xenc:CipherData>
                <xenc:CipherValue>XXX</xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
        </xenc:EncryptedData>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Oh and I realize WSE3 is obsolete...